# Evaluating this complicated integral using complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to evaluate this integral:

$$\boxed{\int_{-\pi}^\pi\sin(2\cos\theta)\cos((2m+1)\theta)\,d\theta}$$
where $m\in\mathbb{N}$, using complex analysis methods.

What I have done is to find the residue of $\sin(z+\frac 1z)$:

Since $$\sin(z+\frac 1z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k(z+z^{-1})^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$$, and using the Binomial theorem, we have $$(z+z^{-1})^{2k+1}=\sum_{r=0}^{2k+1}{{2k+1}\choose r}z^{2k+1-2r}$$.

Combining these two facts we have that the residue (coefficient of $z^{-1}$) is:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}{{2k+1}\choose{k+1}}$$.

After this I am kind of stuck.

I am aware of the standard technique of substituting $\cos\theta=\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}$, $d\theta=\frac{dz}{iz}$, etc, but I am not sure what to do with the $\cos((2m+1)\theta)$.

Thanks for any help.

By the way, if it helps, the answer I am supposed to get is $$\boxed{2\pi\sum_{k=m}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}{{2k+1}\choose {k-m}}}$$.

Update: Using David Holden's excellent hint, I proceded to find the residue of the integrand.

So the integral becomes $\frac{1}{2i}\int_C\sin(z+z^{-1})(z^{2m}+z^{-2m-2})\,dz$.

I find the residue of the integrand to be

$$\sum_{k=m}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}{{2k+1}\choose{k+m+1}}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}{{2k+1}\choose{k-m}}$$

I may have made a mistake along the way, I can't get to the final answer.

Comment: We have that $\cos(n\theta)=T_n\cos(\theta)$ where $T_n$ is the [Chebyshev Polynomial of the First Kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheFirstKind.html).  Once you get the polynomial in $\cos\theta$ (which is what $T_n\cos\theta$ is), you should be able to substitute in $\cos\theta = \frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}$.  While this seems like it might work, it also seems like it'd suck a lot.

Comment: $\cos(2m+1)\theta = \frac12(z^{2m+1}+z^{-(2m+1)})$

Comment: One approach (which, alas, doesn't fit your desire for a complex-analysis proof) is to appeal to the [Jacobi-Anger expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion).  Specifically, you can use the second real-valued expression listed there to get the result as a Bessel function evaluated at $z=2$.

Comment: @Semiclassical thanks though, I learnt something.

Comment: when you have those $Res(e^{a z+b/z},0)$ it becomes the (complicated) value of Bessel functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that $\cos{\left [ (2 m+1) \theta \right ]} = \operatorname{Re}{\left [e^{i (2 m+1) \theta}\right ]} $.  Then we consider the integral

$$-i \oint_{|z|=1} dz \, \sin{\left ( z+\frac1{z} \right )} z^{2 m}$$

which is equal to $i 2 \pi$ times the sum of the residues of the integrand at $z=0$.  To evaluate the residues and their sum, we Taylor expand the sine term to get, as the integrand,

$$-i \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2 k+1)!} \left ( z+\frac1{z} \right )^{2 k+1} z^{2 m} $$

The coefficient of $z^{-1}$ in the $k$th term of the expansion is the coefficient of the $k+m+1$th term.  (You can work this out for successive values of $m$.)  Thus, the integral is equal to

$$2 \pi \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2 k+1)!} \binom{2 k+1}{k+m+1} = 2 \pi \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(k-m)! (k+m+1)!}$$

To evaluate the sum, note that the terms for $k \lt m$ are zero.  Then we can shift the index of the sum to get

$$ 2 \pi \sum_{k=m}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(k-m)! (k+m+1)!} =  2 \pi (-1)^m \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k! (k+2 m+1)!}$$

The latter sum is recognizable as a Bessel function evaluated at $z=2$.  Thus,

> $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} d\theta \, \sin{(2 \cos{\theta})} \cos{\left [ (2 m+1) \theta \right ]} = 2 \pi (-1)^m J_{2 m+1}(2)$$

Comment: Thanks. But how about the other term in $cos(2m+1)\theta=\frac 12(z^{2m+1}+z^{−(2m+1)})$?

Comment: Note that I used the real part from which the cosine is derived.  No need to complicate things with two terms like that.

Comment: Can you elaborately briefly how to use the real part? This is the first time I am seeing it.

Comment: @yoyostein: you have never seen the trick $$\int dx Re[f(x)] = Re \int dx f(x)$$ ?

Comment: ok now I see it, thanks